# AWSCognito connecting Facebook and own developer authenticated identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to connect my AWSCognitoIdentities as referenced here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/

```
// Initialize a Logins map for the authentication tokens.
Map logins = new HashMap();

// Add the custom identity for this user
logins.put("custom", identifier);

// If your user is also logged in with Facebook, Amazon, or Google, we can now add
// the session token.
logins.put("graph.facebook.com", Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken());

// Add the new map we created to the credentials provider.
credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

I am not getting any errors when I run this but I can only see my custom developer authenticated provider linked to the user from the Amazon Console.

Any thoughts on what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you use public identity provider tokens such as facebook with Developer Authenticated Identities, make sure that you transmit these tokens to your backend along with the [GetOpenIDTokenFromDeveloperIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) call when calling Amazon Cognito from your backend. This is mentioned briefly under the "Connect to an Existing Social Identity" section of the [Developer Authenticated Identities topic in the Amazon Cognito Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/#connect-to-an-existing-social-identity).